# Animate a parent element on ng-enter

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css

I have a dropdown menu, and I'd like to animate the dropdown icon with Animate.css's 'bounce' class whenever a new item is added to the dropdown. I have the ngAnimate module installed, and animating the li's works fine, my question is how can I add this css class only when ng-enter is present (ie. when a new list item is added), and only when ng-enter is present?

Code:

```
    <tab class='pull-right' class='ng-isolate-scope'>     
        <tab-heading>
        <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
            <!-- Simple dropdown -->
            <span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
              <a href class="dropdown-toggle {{ disableDropdown }} animated" dropdown-toggle ng-click='showMenu = ! showMenu'>
                <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu port-dropdown-menu" ng-show='showMenu && disableDropdown != "disabled"' >
                <li class='dropdown-list-item' ng-repeat="choice in dropdown.items">
                    <a ui-sref="portfolio.manager.edit({portId: choice.id})">{{ choice.title }}</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </span>
        </div>
        </tab-heading>
    </tab>
```

Edit: it looks like a custom animation that adds the bounce class to the dropdown menu icon, then removes it after a few seconds should work. However, none of the ng-animate features are working on this partial, although they are working on other partials. `console.log('add bounce')` isn't logging 'add bounce' at all, which makes me think ng-animate isn't working on the partial. Here's my animation, which does work when used on other partials:

'use strict';

```
angular.module('portfolioManager.animations', []).animation('.dropdown-list-item', function($timeout) {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('bounce');
      console.log('add bounce')
      $timeout(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('bounce');
        done();
      },2000);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yeah, I do, got any ideas?

Comment: I will take a look at it in a few hours.

Comment: Here is a similar example and it seems to work: http://plnkr.co/edit/BeLAAKL6yu8zISrw0ivm?p=preview Are you sure you have included `portfolioManager.animations` in your main module?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. The animation works in other views in the same directory, just not in this one.

Comment: Can you try to replicate it in a plunker? Otherwise I might try to set it up tomorrow.